# SQL End of Quarter Date Diff and filter

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I have a data set with repeating date values within a quarter, I'd like to select the closest date to the quarter end.

Existing data

[image]

The output I'm tryting to acheive would look like this

[image]

```
select
created_at,
account_id,                                                               
account_name,
Score, 
DATEADD(d, -1, DATEADD(q, DATEDIFF(q, 0, d.Timestamp) + 1, 0)) 
                    AS 'quarterend'
From xyz.database
```

I'm not sure what the best way is to filter out the unneeded values, had thought about a datediff caluation after creating a quarte end date and choose min score in a having or where clause subselect but could not get that to work.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROW_NUMBER can order the account_id's by the datediff between timestamp and quarter end date.  Then you just need to select the first row.

```
with
difs as
(
    select  created_at
          , account_id
          , account_name
          , Score
          , dateadd(d, -1, dateadd(q, datediff(q, 0, d.Timestamp) + 1, 0))                             as 'quarterend'
          , datediff(day, d.Timestamp, dateadd(d, -1, dateadd(q, datediff(q, 0, d.Timestamp) + 1, 0))) as 'quarterenddif'
    from    MyTable
)
select  *
from    (
    select  *
          , row_number() over (partition by quarterend, account_id order by quarterenddif desc) rn
    from    difs
) t
where   rn = 1
```

Comment: Finding this solution drops all records accept the last quarter end transaction for an account, I need to save each quarter end transaction across years so if an account were listed across multiple years and quarters, the output would include 1 value for each year there was a transaction I.e. values for Q12019, Q12022 Q2202, Q42022.  For the example data above account BAC should have 1 output for Q3 and 1 output for Q4

Comment: to get all quarters for an account, you just need to include the quarter end date and partition by that as well.  Answer updated.

Comment: OK that works if you change the order by statement to asc rather than desc